# What kind of object can I send to this view in order to get this PHP code to work?

Tags: php, pdo

I am terrible at PHP and I need to retrieve data from a database and give it to an index.php view. The view is pre-made and has this code:

```
//This is simplified - it has error handling that is not shown
$results = getAll($tableName);

//This is the line where it is failing
//Undefined Offset
$columns = empty($results) ? array() : array_keys($results[0]);
$idColumn = $columns[0];
```

There is all the rest of it but I just need to know what on earth it is that this bit of code is expecting. I have not even got the first clue what is supposed to be sent to this thing. I just need to get it to work.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function getAll($tablename)
{
    $mysqlConnection = getDbConnection();//Just the normal PDO db connection
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
    $sth = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $resultSet = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

I have tried various different PDO::FETCH_... types but nothing is working. There is no information about what it is that I am supposed to send that part of the view.

Comment: `var_dump($results)` and see the structure of the array. If you want all the rows from `fetch()`, you will need to loop through the result and place them in an array. You can use `fetchAll()` instead. One other thing is that when you use FETCH_ASSOC the keys are the column names not number.

Comment: @frz3993 - you could write that as an answer and get some points. fetchAll() did it. I presume it just needed the entire set because it handles it all in the view somehow. Like I said - I am bad with PHP... as simple as that was. It is basically me thinking it was more complicated than what it really was!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the rows from `fetch()`, you will need to loop through the result set because it will return a single row. In the loop you can place them in an array.

You can use `fetchAll()` instead. It will return all the results as an array.

Comment: Only problem now is that I am getting duplicate columns with a number at the top instead of the name. It is not really a part of this question though - I will probably work out how to fix it.

Comment: Got it... FETCH_NAMED! Resolved. Thank you for the help.